# Using "Rows between 1 Following and 1 Following in Teradata" to Select the next row's values

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to select the next row's value into a another column.  However, I get both the current and next value..

The SQL query being used is the following:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  "Title",
  "US Release Date Title",
  MAX("Title") OVER (
    PARTITION BY "Brand"
    ORDER BY "US Release Date Title" DESC, "Title" DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING
) AS "Predecessor"
```

And a snippet the output from that query is this:

```
Call of Duty: Black Ops IIII    |  2018-10-12  |  Call of Duty: Black Ops IIII    |  2018-10-12
Call of Duty: Black Ops IIII    |  2018-10-12  |  Call of Duty: WWII              |  2017-11-03
Call of Duty: WWII              |  2017-11-03  |  Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare  |  2016-11-04
Call of Duty: WWII              |  2017-11-03  |  Call of Duty: WWII              |  2017-11-03
Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare  |  2016-11-04  |  Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare  |  2014-11-03
Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare  |  2016-11-04  |  Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare  |  2016-11-04
Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare  |  2014-11-03  |  null                            |  null
Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare  |  2014-11-03  |  Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare  |  2014-11-03
```

My desired output is this:
And a snippet the output from that query is this:

```
Call of Duty: Black Ops IIII    |  2018-10-12  |  Call of Duty: WWII              |  2017-11-03
Call of Duty: WWII              |  2017-11-03  |  Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare  |  2016-11-04
Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare  |  2016-11-04  |  Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare  |  2014-11-03
Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare  |  2014-11-03  |  null                            |  null
```

Comment: That's only part of the query, but my guess is that you have duplicates in the data. Instead of applying DISTINCT at the end, use a subquery to remove duplicates first. Then your windowed MAX should give the desired results

Comment: Currently you got each row twice in your base data. Fix this and your problem is resolved. Btw, *predecessor* translates to `MAX("Title") OVER (
    PARTITION BY "Brand"
    ORDER BY "US Release Date Title" DESC, "Title"
    ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
)` or `LAG("Title") OVER (
    PARTITION BY "Brand"
    ORDER BY "US Release Date Title" DESC, "Title")` if you're on TD16.10+

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the `select distinct` *before* the window function.  Or use aggregation:

```
SELECT "Title", "US Release Date Title",
       MAX("Title") OVER (PARTITION BY MAX("Brand")
                          ORDER BY "US Release Date Title" DESC,
                                   "Title" DESC
                          ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING
                          ) AS "Predecessor"
FROM t
GROUP BY "Title", "US Release Date Title";
```

You do need an aggregation function around `Brand` for this to work.